# Updating multiple tables with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I understand that you can select multiple columns from multiple tables by using joins.  Is it possible to update multiple columns in multiple tables using joins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Nope.**

You can only do an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` into one table at a time.

If you need to do multiples, you can enclose them in a transaction to make sure they all pass or fail together, though:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE Table1
SET Col1=Value1

UPDATE Table2
SET Col2=Value2

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK
<error message reporting here>
END CATCH
```

Comment: You also need some form of error handling - otherwise, if there's an error in the first update, it's reported, then it goes ahead and performs the second update and commits the transaction.

Comment: @Damien - true, I just didn't add it.  I'll throw some on there in a moment.

Comment: (Just hit edit to move the first two lines of code into a code block)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, unless you use triggers on the underlying table