# The multi-part identifier "Offers.OfferDescription" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I make grid that results from joining 2 tables CustomerInfo and Offers
Made the column of Offers.OfferDescription as dropdownlist, and when it comes to edit mode, it turn to textbox and when I update I get that error

```
The multi-part identifier "Offers.OfferDescription" could not be bound
```

and this is my code for selecting

```
SELECT CustomerInfo.NationalID, CustomerInfo.FNama, CustomerInfo.LName,      
CustomerInfo.MobileNumber, Offers.OfferDescription 
FROM CustomerInfo INNER JOIN Offers ON CustomerInfo.OfferID = Offers.OfferID 
WHERE (CustomerInfo.UserName = @UserName)
```

and this is my code for updating

```
UPDATE      CustomerInfo
SET         PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber, Offers.OfferDescription = @OfferDescription, FNama = @FNama, LName = @LName, OfferID = @OfferID
FROM        CustomerInfo AS CustomerInfo_1 INNER JOIN Offers ON CustomerInfo_1.OfferID = Offers.OfferID CROSS JOIN CustomerInfo
```

Comment: try to run the UPDATE statement in SQL Management studio, passing or replacing the parameters, I guess it does not work either, you have to fix the issue there...

Comment: Whyy is this even tagged "VB.NET" - there is only SQL. Why don't you also tag it with what you ate for breakfast? Same relevance. This is a pure "I have a problem writing a SQL update statement" type of problem. No VB.NET involved.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update Offers.OfferDescription in an update of CustomerInfo ....

```
UPDATE      CustomerInfo
```

SET         PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber, `Offers.OfferDescription =`

You can't update a column of a foreign table (b) in an update of table (a).

Answer (score 0):

You can only do an UPDATE or INSERT into one table at a time ([Updating multiple tables with inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665809/updating-multiple-tables-with-inner-join)). In your update query, you are trying to update two tables. Please try to update using two queries like:

```
UPDATE      CustomerInfo
SET         PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber,  FNama = @FNama, LName = @LName, OfferID = @OfferID
FROM        CustomerInfo, Offers
WHERE       CustomerInfo.OfferID = Offers.OfferID
```

and

```
UPDATE      Offers
SET         OfferDescription = @OfferDescription
FROM        CustomerInfo, Offers
WHERE       CustomerInfo.OfferID = Offers.OfferID
```

(Please confirm about the column names used in the set operation)

Comment: you`re right.
what I really want to do is, the customer fill the form and choose any offer, then when I show him the grid, he has the option to change offer he chose, that`s why I`m trying to do that. 
will your solution fix it for me ?